# Injective continuous operators between Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two infinite dimensional Banach spaces. What can we say about the set of all injective continuous linear operators between $X$ and $Y$? Is it always nonempty?

Comment: What if $X$ is a non-separable Hilbert space, and $Y$ is a separable one?

Comment: Or more generally, if the Hamel dimension of $X$ is larger than that of $Y$.  Then there will be no injective linear operators at all, never mind continuous.

Comment: The answers here show that your second question fails  but I think that you have defined an interesting preorder on the  family of Banach spaces:  $X$ is dominated by $Y$ if such an injection exists. Call the corresponding equivalence relation “weak equivalence”.  There is a number of easy pickings (stability properties, etc) that one can quickly deal with but also  many interesting questions, in particular, on weak equivalence of specific spaces.  I would start with:  when is $C(K)$ dominated by (equivalent to) $C(L)$? There is a plethora of such questions for the classical Banach  spaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course the dimension is an obvious obstacle, but even if the space have the same cardinality of Hamel bases the answer is no. For example in the paper

**A. Avilés, P. Koszmider,** 
A Banach space in which every injective operator is surjective.
*Bull. Lond. Math. Soc.* 45 (2013), no. 5, 1065–1074

the authors constructed an infinitely dimensional Banach space $X$ such that if $T:X\to X$ is bounded and injective, then $T(X)=X$. Therefore if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, then one cannot find an injective operator $T:X\to Y$.

Answer (score 5):

Piotr Hajłasz' answer nails the problem, however, let me point out that there are easier examples of such pairs of spaces among spaces that have the same density.

Suppose that $X$ fails to have a strictly convex renorming. Thus, there is no injective operator $T$ from $X$ into any space $Y$ that is strictly convex, as if it were $\|x\|^\prime = \|x\| + \|Tx\|$ would be a strictly convex norm on $X$.

Spaces that do not have a strictly convex norm include

- $X = \ell_\infty^c(\Gamma)$, the space of all bounded scalar-valued functions on an uncountable set $\Gamma$ that have at most countable support (Day);
- $X = \ell_\infty / c_0$ (Bourgain).

In the latter case, you may even take $Y= \ell_\infty$.

Comment: Is it absolute that there is an example where the density character of both spaces is $\aleph_1$? Are there examples where both spaces are reflexive and have the same density character?

Comment: @BillJohnson, for reflexive it is even easier: take $X = \ell_p(\Gamma)$ and $Y=\ell_q(\Gamma)$ for $q>p$. By Pitt's theorem, every operator from $X$ to $Y$ is compact, hence it has separable range. But an injection will be a homeomorphic embedding of the weakly compact unit balls; a contradiction.

Comment: Duh, now. :)  (Actually, I was thinking about not having an injective operator in either direction when I asked that stupid question.)